# How to fix: Abort called in C++ Hackerank?

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, algorithm, web

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);

/*
 * Complete the 'maximumDraws' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts INTEGER n as parameter.
 */

int maximumDraws(int n) {
     int t;
     cin >> t;
     int rez;
     for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
             cin >> n;
     }   
     
     for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
             cout << n++ << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    string t_temp;
    getline(cin, t_temp);

    int t = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(t_temp)));

    for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
        string n_temp;
        getline(cin, n_temp);

        int n = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(n_temp)));

        int result = maximumDraws(n);

        fout << result << "\n";
    }

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

string ltrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        s.begin(),
        find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace)))
    );

    return s;
}

string rtrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))).base(),
        s.end()
    );

    return s;
}
```

The error is: Abort called: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'...i try to fix this, i tried
I have been trying to solve this problem for 3 days, but every time with any method of solving I get this error. I asked in other places but I did not receive a relevant answer. Please i need help, how can i fix it?

Hackerrank link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-draws/problem?isFullScreen=true

Comment: Run your code on your machine with a debugger and see where the exception is thrown. Doesn't make sense to submit any solutions to hackerrank if you didn't check if the code works.

Comment: Why are you performing user input in `maximumDraws`? That seems...weird. But then again I'm not sure what it's actually supposed to be doing. Right now it looks like it does a bunch of input that has no effect, then a bunch of output, then returns `0` unconditionally.

Comment: Functions like [std::stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) throw "std::invalid_argument if no conversion could be performed". Check the argument you're passing to it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your error condition is arising due to mixing your input methods of "getline" and "cin".  The following line:

```
cin >> n;
```

is basically capturing a number.  Most likely after that number is entered, the return key (enter key) is pressed which then contains a newline character which cannot by converted from a string to an integer.  That is probably not exactly an accurate statement, but the act of pressing the enter key seems to be the cause.

To test that out, I replaced the simple "cin >> t" and "cin >> n" code with "getline" calls instead.

```
int maximumDraws(int n)
{
    int t;
    string x_temp;
    getline(cin, x_temp);
    t = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(x_temp)));
    int rez;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, x_temp);
        n = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(x_temp)));
    }
```

That seemed to address your program dump.

The bottom line is be careful in mixing your input methods.  Hope that helps.

Regards.